# First line of PHP database will not wrap in table on webpage

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm working on a form that submits from the form to a MySQL database row. Then, the rows show to users who are logged in.

The part I have been stuck on forever is how to get the responses from the form to word-wrap inside the table I made. I finally managed to do it, except now the first line of each table box is not wrapping. Only whatever comes after it.

This is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pr_bgcslogs");

echo "<span>
<table border='10'>

<tr>
<th>BGCS_ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Alts</th>
<th>Experience</th>
<th>DELETE</th>
</tr>";



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

echo "<tr>"; 

echo "<td>" . $row['BGCS_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Rank'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $message = $row['Alts'];
$wrappedmessage = wordwrap($message, 50, "<br/>", true);
echo "$wrappedmessage<br/>". "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Experience'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='/pts/admin/modules/delete.php?id=".$row['BGCS_ID']."'>X</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

As you can see, I am just testing the wrapping only on the 'Alts' column. But it shows up like this:

[Wrap Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW2Zs.png)

Comment: You just have a typo... you are using `.` instead of `;` in this line: `echo "<td>" . $message = $row['Alts'];`  Using `.` means that $message is getting echoed before you do the wordwrap, so you are outputting the text twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a way around it, using the following code:

```
echo "<tr>"; 
$username = $row['Username'];
$rank = $row['Rank'];
$alts = $row['Alts'];
$experience = $row['Experience'];
echo "<td>" . $row['BGCS_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $wrappedmessage = wordwrap($username, 30, "<br/>", true); "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $wrappedmessage = wordwrap($rank, 30, "<br/>", true); "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $wrappedmessage = wordwrap($alts, 30, "<br/>", true); "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $wrappedmessage = wordwrap($experience, 30, "<br/>", true); "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='/pts/admin/modules/delete.php?id=".$row['BGCS_ID']."'>X</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that there is no end tag ?
In this place

```
echo "<td>" . $message = $row['Alts'];
```

Comment: They *are* echoing the end tag, its just not in the same `echo` statement.